# How many predicables does Aristotle have?

Tags: aristotle

Some writers claim that Aristotle has 4 predicables: definition, preperty, genus & accident; some other writers however claim 5 with the additional differentia. So what exactly is the case strictly according to Aristotle? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accoding to [*Topics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topics_(Aristotle)), they are four; see 101b11-101b29:

> arguments start with propositions, while the subjects on which deductions take place are problems. Now every proposition and every problem indicates either a *genus* or a *property* or an *accident* — for the *differentia* too, being generic, should be ranked together with the genus. Since, however, of what is proper to anything part signifies its essence, while part does not, let us divide the proper into both the aforesaid parts, and call that part which indicates the essence a *definition*, while of the remainder let us adopt the terminology which is generally current about these things, and speak of it as a property.
>
> What we have said, then, makes it clear that according to our present division, the elements turn out to be four, all told, namely either *property* or *definition* or *genus* or *accident*.

See also [Alexander of Aphrodisias](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/alexander-aphrodisias/) (fl.200 AD) commentary [On Aristotle Topics 1](https://books.google.it/books?id=TpkjAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA67), page 67:

> there are four kinds in which [...]: definition, distictive property, genus and accidental [...]

It seems that with [Porphyry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porphyry_(philosopher)) (c.234 – c.305 AD)'s [*Eisagōgḗ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isagoge), one of the most familiar handbooks of logic in the early Middle Ages, the *predicables* (commonly known under the title *quinque voces*) became five, with "species" in place of "definition".

Thus, as is apparent from the above text, *Topics* itself strongly supports the traditional fivefold classification.

---

See also 103b20:

> Next, then, we must distinguish between the categories of predication in
> which the four above-mentioned are found. These are ten in number: What a thing
> is, Quantity, Quality, Relation, Place, Time, Position, State, Activity, Passivity. [See [Aristolte's Logic: Categories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#Cat) and [Aristotle's Categories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-categories/)].

Thus, in the analysis of the basic relation of "predication" (*katêgorein*) we have a (quite obscure) interplay between "types of predication" and "categories" (*katêgoria*).

See e.g. Michael Frede, [Categories in Aristotle](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.5749/j.cttttpfd).

Comment: Did you mean differentia is sort of some sub-classification within genus?

Comment: What about [the 10 predicaments/categories](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/37148/2014)?

Comment: @Geremia, could you elaborate on your question?

Comment: @Geremia - *Topics* is concerned with "arguments" and deductions; it speaks of *problems* and we may say that a "problem" is expressed by a sentence (categorical proposition) asserting of something (i.e. predicating of) "what it is". This "what" can be fourfold: a *definition* (the essence), a *unique property*, a *genus* (including the *differentia*) or an *accident*. Man is a *rational animal* (definition), *rationality* being its unique prop; its genus is *animal* and two-handed is an accidental property.

Comment: *Categories* is clearly more "ontological minded": categories are different kind of entities. They are naturally related to the "basic" relation of *predication*: "Of things said without combination, each signifies either: (i) a substance (*ousia*); (ii) a quantity; (iii) a quality; ..." Thus, they are the (ten) different ways an "entity" (the constituent of facts) may be classified.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Re: «_[Aristotle's categories (or predicables, as I'm arguing they can also be called)] are naturally related to the "basic" relation of_ predication». If predication is a relation, and relation is one of Aristotle's 10 categories/predicables, then it would seem Aristotle has more than 4 predicables.

Comment: @sonny Aristotle's _Categories_ is called _Categoriæ seu De **Predicamentis**_ in Latin.

Comment: @Geremia, not being an Aristotelian scholar, let me venture to reply as such: the ten categories are attributes (predicamenta) which can be used to talk about things, whereas the four predicables have to do with kinds (?) of predication.

Comment: @Geremia and sonny - the issue is thorny and I'm not a scholar... Philosophers and philologists are discussing from 350 BCE: this means that the interpretation of A's works is not easy. Havinfg said that, we must take into account at least two issues: different A's works written in different times with different "contexts". The "evolution" of A's thought has never been completely assesed (see at least [W.Jaeger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_Jaeger) and [I.During](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingemar_D%C3%BCring)) and thus we are not sure if *Top* and *Cat* reflects different phases.

Comment: The second point is language: what is sure is the central rose of the "predicative" relation in A's logic and ontology; but then, how correctly transaltes the term [*katêgorein*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#GloAriTer) and its derivatives? Why *categories* and *predicables* ? The origin is (I think) the medieval tradition from Porphyry and Boetius on: this means an *interpretation* and using it to "elucidate" A's original thought can make it more difficult.

Comment: From Greek ancient commentators to today the discussion about [categories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#Cat) is still "alive and well": are they logico-lingusitic or ontological ? See e.g. [A. Trendelenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Adolf_Trendelenburg) and his [Geschicte der Kategorienlehre](https://books.google.it/books?id=JQVRAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover) and [Outlines of Logic](https://archive.org/details/outlineslogican00trengoog) and ... 1/2

Comment: ... [H.Bonitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Bonitz)'s [Über die Kategorien des A.](https://books.google.it/books?id=2F0-AAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover). The "reasonable" answer is: both. 2/2

Comment: See also Allan Bäck, [Aristotle's Theory of Predication](https://books.google.it/books?id=LbG1v0RAtRwC&pg=PA1) (2000).