# Aristotle's Categories with academic commentary

Tags: reference-request, aristotle

I am looking for books on Aristotle's Categories with academic commentary, preferably with references to further development of logic.

Comment: See SEP's entry on [Aristotle's Categories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-categories/) with biblio.

Comment: The site ontology.co has  refs to commentaries in various languges e.g. https://www.ontology.co/biblio/aristotle-categories-biblio-one.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third treatise, "On [Predicament](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/37138/2014)s*" ("*De prædicamentis*"), of the [*Summulæ<sup>†</sup> Logicales*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5830) (PDF pp. 65-77) by [Peter of Spain](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peter-spain/)<sup>‡</sup> is a commentary on Aristotle's *Categories*.

<sup>*"[Predicament](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/37138/2014)s" is another word for "Categories".
†*Summulæ*, or "little summary works," are works written for beginners.
‡Petrus Hispanus or Pope John XXI, d. 1277</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Aristotle, Aristotle's Categories and De Interpretatione, Published by Clarendon Press, Oxford, 1963. Translated with notes by J.L.Ackrill. Ackrill was a fine scholar and I still find this book reliable.

Jonathan Barnes is a principal expert on Aristotle and the relevant part of his Aristotle: A Very Short Introduction, ISBN 10: 0192854089 / ISBN 13: 9780192854087 Oxford University Press is worth a scan.

Markus Kohl, 'Substancehood and Subjecthood in Aristotle's "Categories"', Phronesis, Vol. 53, No. 2 (2008), pp. 152-179 repays attention.

Wolfgang-Rainer Mann, The Discovery of Things: Aristotle's Categories and Their Context, 
Published by Princeton University Press, United States (2000) ISBN 10: 069101020X ISBN 13: 9780691010205 is not an easy but certainly a valuable read.

As to the connection of the Categories with later developments in logic, 
Kneale, William ; Kneale, Martha, The Development of Logic, ISBN 10: 0198247737 / ISBN 13: 9780198247739, Clarendon Press/ Oxford University Press, 1991, is useful.

**The authenticity of the Categories**

The question has been put to me :

> Do any of these authors question Aristotle's authorship of the Categories? Bocheński writes in History of Formal Logic p. 40: "the Categories alone is seriously considered to be spurious.

I offer the following information.

There are three separate questions : about the authenticity of (a) the Categories as a whole, (b) Cat. ch. 1 - 9, and (c) Cat.10-15.

All these matters have been investigated by  L. M. de Rijk, 'The Authenticity of Aristotle's Categories',  Mnemosyne, Fourth Series, Vol. 4, Fasc. 2 (1951), pp. 129-159. (There is earlier work by Isaac Husik, William David Ross
The Journal of Philosophy, Vol. 36, No. 16 (Aug. 3, 1939), pp. 427-433. A large body of 19th-century German scholarship should also be mentioned. I keep to 
de Rijk.)

*The Categories as a whole*

> We may draw the following conclusions from this part of our
>    investigation :
>    1. All the ancient commentators are themselves convinced of the
>    authenticity of the Categories.
>    2. Only two Anonymi mention any arguments against it, but
>    such arguments are merely academic hypotheses which they
>    themselves reject. (de Rijk : 139.)

*Cat. 1 - 9*

> To sum up our conclusions:
>    1). The view about *ousia* in the Categories is nearer to Plato's than
>    that of the Metaphysics.
>    2). The starting-point of the investigations about true substance
>    (in Metaph. Z 1) agrees very well with the view of the Categories;
>    there is a continuous line of thought running from the Categories
>    to the definitive doctrine about *ousia* (in Metaph. Z 17).
>    3). The originality and early formulation of the doctrine about
>   *ousia* in the Categories strongly supports the authenticity of the
>    treatise (Categories Chs. 1-9). (de Rijk : 149.)

*Cat, 10 - 15*

These chapters, the so-called Postpraedicamenta, have been widely regarded as spurious but have had distinguished modern defenders - e.g. Sir David Ross and L. Minio-Paluello (de Rijk : 149.). Jonathan Barnes, a principal Aristotelian scholar, in his revised translation of the Oxford Aristotle (Princeton, 1984, vol. 1) accepts the Categories as genuinely Aristotelian.

There is a problem, though, in that there is some kind of dividing line between 1 - 9 and 10 - 15 :

> d that there is undoubtedly a dividing-line
>    between Chs. 1-9 and Chs 10-15. This disjointedness has always
>    been observed 3). It is noticeable, moreover, that for Hamelin, who
>    believes the teaching of Chs. 10-15 to be thouroughly Aristotelian,
>    it is only the disjointedness that gives any grounds for doubting the
>    authenticity. It is obvious that the treatise should be considered
>    as a separate entity. By doing so we can explain adequately why
>    the term e?e??, which is already spoken about (or rather "dis-
>    missed") in Categ. Ch. 9,1 lbl2 ff., is dealt with once again in Categ.
>    Ch. 15. ((de Rijk : 159.)

The texts on my original list, save for Barnes, do not discuss the question of authenticity since the Categories has largely been regarded by scholars of the last half-century as genuine. Since Bocheński  is not a leading voice in contemporary Aristotelian scholarship, and in the absence of any grounds he gives for his opinion, I am reluctant to surrender the authenticity of the Categories on the basis of the reference you give.

Comment: Do any of these authors question Aristotle's authorship of the _Categories_? Bocheński writes in [_History of Formal Logic_ p. 40](https://archive.org/details/historyofformall00boch/page/40): "the _Categories_ alone is seriously considered to be spurious."

Comment: @Geremia. I have responded to your indeed pertinent question in my revised answer. I hope to have been of assistance. Best : GT

Comment: New papers have been written after Rijk in 1952, but interestingly the debate on authenticity seem more lively in French see e.g. Achard M., 2000, Laval. theol.56(2)  https://www.erudit.org/en/journals/ltp/2000-v56-n2-ltp2167/401302ar.pdf

Comment: I do not know French... Thanks anyway...