# Traditional beginner's commentary on Aristotle's categories

Tags: logic, reference-request, aristotle

I am looking for a traditional beginner's commentary on Aristotle's categories in order to start learning Aristotle's system of logic.

Even better would be a "road map" for studying Aristotle's logic through commentaries. I aim to eventually be able to read and understand Aquinas's commentary on the Posterior Analytics, as well as other works of Aristotle such as his Physics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of "[Aristotle's Categories with academic commentary](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/56368/2014)." (cf. "[In Aristotle, What does it mean for something to be predicated?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/37138/2014)")